# Clear UIImageView what is drawn with touch

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimageview

I have class Canvas inherited from  **UIImageView** (at the background is set image background.png) and and in method touchesMoved I draw gesture of some color:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self];  

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size); 
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  

[self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, width);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, red, green, blue, alpha);
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, location.x, location.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

location = currentLocation;
```

I have ERASE button bellow, how to clear context of canvas but to keep background.png as background, only remove what user draw with touch( I have property canvas ) ?

Answer (score 2):

You could just draw a transparent rect over the image view, like this:

[CoreGraphics: Image Transparent Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593717/coregraphics-image-transparent-background)